# Tabs in Android, how to create content

Tags: android, eclipse, tabs, fragment

Hey I'm quite new to creating android apps. I want to create three Tabs in the Actionbar. I've already done this by creating them using New->Android Activity-> Navigation with Swipe and Tabs.

So that's my code of the MainActivity (used one of android.com's tutorials):

```
 public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
            // number argument value.
            int current_section = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

            switch(current_section){
            case 1:
            {

                EditText element1 = new EditText(getActivity());
                element1.setHint(R.string.edit_text_hint);
                element1.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
                element1.setPadding(40,40,40,0);
                element1.setSingleLine();

                TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setText("Search");


                return element1;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setText("User Account");
                return textView;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setText("Last Updated");
                return textView;
            }
            }
            TextView textView1 = new TextView(getActivity());
            textView1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
//          textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
//                  ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return textView1;
        }
    }
```

So in each of the three Tabs there is a different Item display, unfortunatelly it is only possible to display one - and not more. I think it's quite an easy question but I'm just not figuring out how this could work.
Hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tutorial, you are returning a **textview**. Try to add the textview to a Layout, and return the layout.

I think what you want is use different fragments for different tabs. You can then specify your layout and other code in the fragment itself, instead of building one BIG fragment with a switch case.

For every **Fragment** you create a new class. This **Fragment** can be added to a **TabBarListener**.

In the **onCreateView** of **Fragment**, you can create your layout programmatically by adding objects to the **view** parameter. You can also use the inflator to inflate your XML layout.

I created a sample project, were 1 **Fragment** view is inflated, the other is created programmatically:

[here](http://www.mor-it.nl/code/stackoverflow/ActionBarFragment.zip)

If you read the android documentation it will be much more clear. I think they even have a sample code project.

[Actiobar, the tab sections](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

[More info about fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example)

Comment: okay, i thought about something like that. So how to do that exactly? Should I use a seperate xml file for each tab or define the layout for each tab in the MainActivity.class? Thanks for your quick help :)

Comment: i updated the answer. Take a while to read the documentation. It's all there.

Comment: And don't forget to Mark (V) / Upvote (^) the correct answer on the left of the answer ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've tried for hours to get this working and I'm just failing. I've tried your links and a lot of code examples, but whenever I try to do it myself, it just isn't working as I want it to do. Maybe you got some really good example or can give me a code etc. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I added a link to a sample project. Good luck

Comment: Hey there, thank you very much. :) I've finally made it. I would upvote you, but that's not possible as I don't have 15 reputation yet.

Comment: Hey Oritm, question for you. If I am using Fragment for tabs, does the buttons and the button action code has to be inside the Fragment class or the MainActivity class? Because I have a button inside a Fragment but the codes are in MainActivity and it gives me a NPE.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. You can write this code in whatever class you want. Because the MainActivity class instantiate the Fragments, you need a listener to call the buttons action code in the MainActivity.